# How do I use a Python package from Python package exchange in Pycharm Mac?

Tags: python, macos, pip, pycharm

## Note

I am a beginner in Python and using Pycharm.

## The Problem

I am trying to use a project from pypi.org/. I noticed it said pip install "name of project". I did some looking around on the internet and it seems like in order to do that in Pycharm I need to create a Pipenv environment. However, I don't understand how to set this up and how to use it. If I don't need a Pipenv environment what do I need to do instead?

## What I've tried

I went to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pipenv.html to try to figure out how to create the Pipenv environment but it wasn't working for me and was also confusing for me.

Comment: Do you use a specific distribution like Anaconda? If not, have you downloaded a version of Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Pycharm UI to handle packages as mentioned in their [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).